# How to count files inside zip in AWS S3 without downloading it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Case: 
There is a large zip file in an S3 bucket which contains a large number of images. Is there a way without downloading the whole file to read the metadata or something to know how many files are inside the zip file?

When the file is local, in python i can just open it as a zipfile() and then I call the namelist() method which returns a list of all the files inside, and I can count that. However not sure how to do this when the file resides in S3 without having to download it. Also if this is possible with Lambda would be best.

Comment: Have a look at [the listing logic used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351000/read-zip-files-from-s3-without-downloading-the-entire-file/52455004#52455004) if you want to do this with the minimal possible bandwidth usage (_might_ be optimizable a bit more, though ;))

Comment: There is a [github](https://github.com/hkutluay/S3ZipContent/) project for anyone needs on .net environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
import zlib
import zipfile
import io

def fetch(key_name, start, len, client_s3):
    """
    range-fetches a S3 key
    """
    end = start + len - 1
    s3_object = client_s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name, Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (start, end))
    return s3_object['Body'].read()


def parse_int(bytes):
    """
    parses 2 or 4 little-endian bits into their corresponding integer value
    """
    val = (bytes[0]) + ((bytes[1]) << 8)
    if len(bytes) > 3:
        val += ((bytes[2]) << 16) + ((bytes[3]) << 24)
    return val


def list_files_in_s3_zipped_object(bucket_name, key_name, client_s3):
    """

    List files in s3 zipped object, without downloading it. Returns the number of files inside the zip file.
    See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789176/how-to-count-files-inside-zip-in-aws-s3-without-downloading-it
    Based on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351000/read-zip-files-from-s3-without-downloading-the-entire-file


    bucket_name: name of the bucket
    key_name:  path to zipfile inside bucket
    client_s3: an object created using boto3.client("s3")
    """

    bucket = bucket_name
    key = key_name

    response = client_s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
    size = response['ContentLength']

    eocd = fetch(key_name, size - 22, 22, client_s3)

    # start offset and size of the central directory
    cd_start = parse_int(eocd[16:20])
    cd_size = parse_int(eocd[12:16])

    # fetch central directory, append EOCD, and open as zipfile!
    cd = fetch(key_name, cd_start, cd_size, client_s3)
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(cd + eocd))

    print("there are %s files in the zipfile" % len(zip.filelist))

    for entry in zip.filelist:
        print("filename: %s (%s bytes uncompressed)" % (entry.filename, entry.file_size))
    return len(zip.filelist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import boto3
    import sys

    client_s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    bucket_name = sys.argv[1]
    key_name = sys.argv[2]
    list_files_in_s3_zipped_object(bucket_name, key_name, client_s3)
```

Comment: Is there a way of using this for files larger than 4GB?

Comment: The idea will still work, but the code would need some heavy refactoring to include that case.

Answer (score 3):

I improved the already given solution - now it handles also files which are larger than 4GiB:

```
import boto3
import io
import struct
import zipfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

EOCD_RECORD_SIZE = 22
ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE = 56
ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE = 20

MAX_STANDARD_ZIP_SIZE = 4_294_967_295

def lambda_handler(event):
    bucket = event['bucket']
    key = event['key']
    zip_file = get_zip_file(bucket, key)
    print_zip_content(zip_file)

def get_zip_file(bucket, key):
    file_size = get_file_size(bucket, key)
    eocd_record = fetch(bucket, key, file_size - EOCD_RECORD_SIZE, EOCD_RECORD_SIZE)
    if file_size <= MAX_STANDARD_ZIP_SIZE:
        cd_start, cd_size = get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd(eocd_record)
        central_directory = fetch(bucket, key, cd_start, cd_size)
        return zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(central_directory + eocd_record))
    else:
        zip64_eocd_record = fetch(bucket, key,
                                  file_size - (EOCD_RECORD_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE),
                                  ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE)
        zip64_eocd_locator = fetch(bucket, key,
                                   file_size - (EOCD_RECORD_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE),
                                   ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE)
        cd_start, cd_size = get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd64(zip64_eocd_record)
        central_directory = fetch(bucket, key, cd_start, cd_size)
        return zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(central_directory + zip64_eocd_record + zip64_eocd_locator + eocd_record))


def get_file_size(bucket, key):
    head_response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    return head_response['ContentLength']

def fetch(bucket, key, start, length):
    end = start + length - 1
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (start, end))
    return response['Body'].read()

def get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd(eocd):
    cd_size = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd[12:16])
    cd_start = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd[16:20])
    return cd_start, cd_size

def get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd64(eocd64):
    cd_size = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd64[40:48])
    cd_start = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd64[48:56])
    return cd_start, cd_size

def parse_little_endian_to_int(little_endian_bytes):
    format_character = "i" if len(little_endian_bytes) == 4 else "q"
    return struct.unpack("<" + format_character, little_endian_bytes)[0]

def print_zip_content(zip_file):
    files = [zi.filename for zi in zip_file.filelist]
    print(f"{len(files)} files: {files}")
```

Comment: Can we also retrieve one file from large ZIP file without downloading? I'm looking for an answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377520/stream-huge-zip-files-on-s3-using-lambda-and-boto3

Comment: It should be possible. I didn't need to implement that, but according to the documentation it can be done. Basically you need EOCD and CD, and then you can find out where local headers are. In local headers, there are information about the corresponding files' sizes. When you have offset and size, you can download just a single file by sending GET with Range header.

Comment: I think `parse_little_endian_to_int` should be parsed to `unsigned`, otherwise we can get negative values for cd_start...

Comment: can you please explain why we are adding `eocd_record` for zip64 format... as in `return zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(central_directory + zip64_eocd_record + zip64_eocd_locator + eocd_record))`.. Since we already have `zip64_eocd_record`, then why do we need `eocd_record` at the end of the  __zip64__ code block `return` statement

Comment: @VivekPuurkayastha take a look at ZIP specification https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT
"4.3.6 Overall .ZIP file format"
```
      [central directory header n]
      [zip64 end of central directory record]
      [zip64 end of central directory locator] 
      [end of central directory record]
```
There are the "standard" EOCD as well as the zip64 EOCD.

Comment: @kwiecien thanks for pointing out the structure ... I was referring to the Wikipedia page on ZIP format and their description of ZIP 64 format could probably have been a bit more categorical...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download a part of archive (first 1Mb at example) and use `jar` tool to see filelist and attributes:

```
jar vt < first-part-of-archive.zip
```

And you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.htm) module to obtain this data in python.

Comment: I am not familiar with Java, and we have no pieces written in Java for this project. How exactly would I use the subprocess module in python to obtain the data? I clicked on the link but got a 404 error.

Comment: To get a part of zip archive, if you have URL you can use methods described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602412/only-download-a-part-of-the-document-using-python-requests). `jar` tool allow to read content of incomplete zip file (python module or `unzip` tool will not work).

Comment: This won't work because the central directory is stored at the rear of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try below s3 command to get count files in gz format

```
aws s3 cp <s3 file uri> - | gunzip -c | grep -i '<Search String>' | wc -l
```

example

```
aws s3 cp s3://test-bucket/test/test.gz - | gunzip -c | grep -i 'test' | wc -l
```

Answer (score -3):

As of now, you cannot get such information without downloading the zip file. You can store the required information as the metadata for a zip file when uploading to s3.

As you have mentioned in your question, using the python functions we are able to get the file list without extracting. You can use the same approach to get the file counts and add as metadata to a particular file and then upload it to S3.

Hope this helps, Thanks