# Read ZIP files from S3 without downloading the entire file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto, zip

We have ZIP files that are 5-10GB in size. The typical ZIP file has 5-10 internal files, each 1-5 GB in size uncompressed.

I have a nice set of Python tools for reading these files. Basically, I can open a filename and if there is a ZIP file, the tools search in the ZIP file and then open the compressed file. It's all rather transparent.

I want to store these files in Amazon S3 as compressed files. I can fetch ranges of S3 files, so it should be possible to fetch the ZIP central directory (it's the end of the file, so I can just read the last 64KiB), find the component I want, download that, and stream directly to the calling process.

So my question is, how do I do that through the standard Python ZipFile API? It isn't documented how to replace the filesystem transport with an arbitrary object that supports POSIX semantics. Is this possible without rewriting the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is the code that allows you to open a file on Amazon S3 as if it were a normal file. Notice I use the `aws` command, rather than the `boto3` Python module. (I don't have access to boto3.)  You can open the file and seek on it. The file is cached locally. If you open the file with the Python ZipFile API and it's a ZipFile, you can then read individual parts.  You can't write, though, because S3 doesn't support partial writes.

Separately, I implement `s3open()`, which can open a file for reading or writing, but it doesn't implement the seek interface, which is required by `ZipFile.`

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from subprocess import run,Popen,PIPE
import copy
import json
import os
import tempfile

# Tools for reading and write files from Amazon S3 without boto or boto3
# http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html
# but it is easier to use the aws cli, since it's configured to work.

def s3open(path, mode="r", encoding=None):
    """
    Open an s3 file for reading or writing. Can handle any size, but cannot seek.
    We could use boto.
    http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html
    but it is easier to use the aws cli, since it is present and more likely to work.
    """
    from subprocess import run,PIPE,Popen
    if "b" in mode:
        assert encoding == None
    else:
        if encoding==None:
            encoding="utf-8"
    assert 'a' not in mode
    assert '+' not in mode

    if "r" in mode:
        p = Popen(['aws','s3','cp',path,'-'],stdout=PIPE,encoding=encoding)
        return p.stdout

    elif "w" in mode:
        p = Popen(['aws','s3','cp','-',path],stdin=PIPE,encoding=encoding)
        return p.stdin
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("invalid mode:{}".format(mode))




CACHE_SIZE=4096                 # big enough for front and back caches
MAX_READ=65536*16
debug=False
class S3File:
    """Open an S3 file that can be seeked. This is done by caching to the local file system."""
    def __init__(self,name,mode='rb'):
        self.name   = name
        self.url    = urlparse(name)
        if self.url.scheme != 's3':
            raise RuntimeError("url scheme is {}; expecting s3".format(self.url.scheme))
        self.bucket = self.url.netloc
        self.key    = self.url.path[1:]
        self.fpos   = 0
        self.tf     = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        cmd = ['aws','s3api','list-objects','--bucket',self.bucket,'--prefix',self.key,'--output','json']
        data = json.loads(Popen(cmd,encoding='utf8',stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0])
        file_info = data['Contents'][0]
        self.length = file_info['Size']
        self.ETag   = file_info['ETag']

        # Load the caches

        self.frontcache = self._readrange(0,CACHE_SIZE) # read the first 1024 bytes and get length of the file
        if self.length > CACHE_SIZE:
            self.backcache_start = self.length-CACHE_SIZE
            if debug: print("backcache starts at {}".format(self.backcache_start))
            self.backcache  = self._readrange(self.backcache_start,CACHE_SIZE)
        else:
            self.backcache  = None

    def _readrange(self,start,length):
        # This is gross; we copy everything to the named temporary file, rather than a pipe
        # because the pipes weren't showing up in /dev/fd/?
        # We probably want to cache also... That's coming
        cmd = ['aws','s3api','get-object','--bucket',self.bucket,'--key',self.key,'--output','json',
               '--range','bytes={}-{}'.format(start,start+length-1),self.tf.name]
        if debug:print(cmd)
        data = json.loads(Popen(cmd,encoding='utf8',stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0])
        if debug:print(data)
        self.tf.seek(0)         # go to the beginning of the data just read
        return self.tf.read(length) # and read that much

    def __repr__(self):
        return "FakeFile<name:{} url:{}>".format(self.name,self.url)

    def read(self,length=-1):
        # If length==-1, figure out the max we can read to the end of the file
        if length==-1:
            length = min(MAX_READ, self.length - self.fpos + 1)

        if debug:
            print("read: fpos={}  length={}".format(self.fpos,length))
        # Can we satisfy from the front cache?
        if self.fpos < CACHE_SIZE and self.fpos+length < CACHE_SIZE:
            if debug:print("front cache")
            buf = self.frontcache[self.fpos:self.fpos+length]
            self.fpos += len(buf)
            if debug:print("return 1: buf=",buf)
            return buf

        # Can we satisfy from the back cache?
        if self.backcache and (self.length - CACHE_SIZE < self.fpos):
            if debug:print("back cache")
            buf = self.backcache[self.fpos - self.backcache_start:self.fpos - self.backcache_start + length]
            self.fpos += len(buf)
            if debug:print("return 2: buf=",buf)
            return buf

        buf = self._readrange(self.fpos, length)
        self.fpos += len(buf)
        if debug:print("return 3: buf=",buf)
        return buf

    def seek(self,offset,whence=0):
        if debug:print("seek({},{})".format(offset,whence))
        if whence==0:
            self.fpos = offset
        elif whence==1:
            self.fpos += offset
        elif whence==2:
            self.fpos = self.length + offset
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("whence={}".format(whence))
        if debug:print("   ={}  (self.length={})".format(self.fpos,self.length))

    def tell(self):
        return self.fpos

    def write(self):
        raise RuntimeError("Write not supported")

    def flush(self):
        raise RuntimeError("Flush not supported")

    def close(self):
        return
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach which does not need to fetch the entire file (full version available [here](https://github.com/janakaud/zip-ninja/blob/master/readers/s3zip.py)).

It does require `boto` (or `boto3`), though (unless you can mimic the ranged `GET`s via AWS CLI; which I guess is quite possible as well).

```
import sys
import zlib
import zipfile
import io

import boto
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat


# range-fetches a S3 key
def fetch(key, start, len):
    end = start + len - 1
    return key.get_contents_as_string(headers={"Range": "bytes=%d-%d" % (start, end)})


# parses 2 or 4 little-endian bits into their corresponding integer value
def parse_int(bytes):
    val = ord(bytes[0]) + (ord(bytes[1]) << 8)
    if len(bytes) > 3:
        val += (ord(bytes[2]) << 16) + (ord(bytes[3]) << 24)
    return val


"""
bucket: name of the bucket
key:    path to zipfile inside bucket
entry:  pathname of zip entry to be retrieved (path/to/subdir/file.name)    
"""

# OrdinaryCallingFormat prevents certificate errors on bucket names with dots
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604689/read-zip-files-from-amazon-s3-using-boto3-and-python#51605244
_bucket = boto.connect_s3(calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat()).get_bucket(bucket)
_key = _bucket.get_key(key)

# fetch the last 22 bytes (end-of-central-directory record; assuming the comment field is empty)
size = _key.size
eocd = fetch(_key, size - 22, 22)

# start offset and size of the central directory
cd_start = parse_int(eocd[16:20])
cd_size = parse_int(eocd[12:16])

# fetch central directory, append EOCD, and open as zipfile!
cd = fetch(_key, cd_start, cd_size)
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(cd + eocd))


for zi in zip.filelist:
    if zi.filename == entry:
        # local file header starting at file name length + file content
        # (so we can reliably skip file name and extra fields)

        # in our "mock" zipfile, `header_offset`s are negative (probably because the leading content is missing)
        # so we have to add to it the CD start offset (`cd_start`) to get the actual offset

        file_head = fetch(_key, cd_start + zi.header_offset + 26, 4)
        name_len = parse_int(file_head[0:2])
        extra_len = parse_int(file_head[2:4])

        content = fetch(_key, cd_start + zi.header_offset + 30 + name_len + extra_len, zi.compress_size)

        # now `content` has the file entry you were looking for!
        # you should probably decompress it in context before passing it to some other program

        if zi.compress_type == zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED:
            print zlib.decompressobj(-15).decompress(content)
        else:
            print content
        break
```

In your case you might need to write the fetched content to a local file (due to large size), unless memory usage is not a concern.

Comment: Your approach interprets the zipfile central directory directly, but you may not implement all of the compression types that python's native zipfile implementation does. If you look at my implementation, I also implement caching and do use ranged queries with the aws cli (I didn't know it could do that when I started, but it can!)

Comment: @vy32 what you say is theoretically true; however (at least in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu Linux) `ZipFile` doesn't support any other compression methods except `STORE` and `DEFLATE` (as per the `ZipFile` docs (`compression: ZIP_STORED (no compression) or ZIP_DEFLATED (requires zlib)`) as well as the implementation; in fact I implemented my decompression logic based on the `ZipFile` sources at `/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py` :)) (And sorry about missing the fact that you were already using ranged queries; seems I didn't read your answer carefully before posting mine!)

Comment: And I tried out your implementation just now, and I must say it's much more elegant than mine (coz it doesn't require you to have any prior knowledge about the `zipfile` module; assuming that `zipfile` only fetches the absolute minimum amount of content required for its operations on-demand - which I believe is very reasonably true!)

Comment: In fact, I traced the execution of the python ZipFile and found that it is optimal, but I discovered that I had to add the caching to make performance decent.

Comment: Well, in fact I was wondering why you had implemented the caching logic; AFAIU once `zipfile` fetches and parses the metadata (central directory and EOCD), all it needs to do when fetching a specific file is to directly seek the appropriate offset and grab the content (local header + compressed data + trailer), correct? In that case, unless you are reading the same entry repeatedly, what's the point in having a cache (unless you are sharing it across multiple instances/runs of your program)?

Comment: Because it reads a few bytes, then reads a few more, then a few more. Try adding some print statements!

Comment: this is brilliant.

Comment: Very helpful, although be aware that this won't handle zip64, meaning if you have over 64K entries you won't be able to access them.  I'm working on adjusting for this, the spec says the entires will be outside the normal central dir.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an improved version of the already given solution - now it uses boto3 and handles files which are larger than 4GiB:

```
import boto3
import io
import struct
import zipfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

EOCD_RECORD_SIZE = 22
ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE = 56
ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE = 20

MAX_STANDARD_ZIP_SIZE = 4_294_967_295

def lambda_handler(event):
    bucket = event['bucket']
    key = event['key']
    zip_file = get_zip_file(bucket, key)
    print_zip_content(zip_file)

def get_zip_file(bucket, key):
    file_size = get_file_size(bucket, key)
    eocd_record = fetch(bucket, key, file_size - EOCD_RECORD_SIZE, EOCD_RECORD_SIZE)
    if file_size <= MAX_STANDARD_ZIP_SIZE:
        cd_start, cd_size = get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd(eocd_record)
        central_directory = fetch(bucket, key, cd_start, cd_size)
        return zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(central_directory + eocd_record))
    else:
        zip64_eocd_record = fetch(bucket, key,
                                  file_size - (EOCD_RECORD_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE),
                                  ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE)
        zip64_eocd_locator = fetch(bucket, key,
                                   file_size - (EOCD_RECORD_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE),
                                   ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE)
        cd_start, cd_size = get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd64(zip64_eocd_record)
        central_directory = fetch(bucket, key, cd_start, cd_size)
        return zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(central_directory + zip64_eocd_record + zip64_eocd_locator + eocd_record))


def get_file_size(bucket, key):
    head_response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    return head_response['ContentLength']

def fetch(bucket, key, start, length):
    end = start + length - 1
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (start, end))
    return response['Body'].read()

def get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd(eocd):
    cd_size = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd[12:16])
    cd_start = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd[16:20])
    return cd_start, cd_size

def get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd64(eocd64):
    cd_size = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd64[40:48])
    cd_start = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd64[48:56])
    return cd_start, cd_size

def parse_little_endian_to_int(little_endian_bytes):
    format_character = "i" if len(little_endian_bytes) == 4 else "q"
    return struct.unpack("<" + format_character, little_endian_bytes)[0]

def print_zip_content(zip_file):
    files = [zi.filename for zi in zip_file.filelist]
    print(f"Files: {files}")
```

Comment: Thanks. However, your solution encodes a lot of knowledge about the zipfile itself, whereas mine leaves that compartmentalized inside the python `zipfile` module. Mine also implements the cache which we found necessary to achieve significant performance.

Comment: Yes, it is different from your solution. It is an updated version of the other solution in this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52455004/8725106

Comment: I struggled a lot with understanding the ZIP specification, so I hope my code snippet can help someone :)

Comment: Your code snippet is useful, and the ZIP specification is confusing with respect to 32-bit vs. 64-bit ZIP files. The advantage of my solution is that you don't need to know the ZIP specification—knowledge of the specification is encapsulated into `zipfile`. Also, the `zipfile` module is well-tested and will likely be kept up-to-date.

Comment: So, if I have `zip_file = get_zip_file(bucket, key)`, why `zip_file.extractall('.')` is not working? It throws `ValueError: negative seek value -2661536`

Answer (score 0):

```
import io


class S3File(io.RawIOBase):
    def __init__(self, s3_object):
        self.s3_object = s3_object
        self.position = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s s3_object=%r>" % (type(self).__name__, self.s3_object)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self.s3_object.content_length

    def tell(self):
        return self.position

    def seek(self, offset, whence=io.SEEK_SET):
        if whence == io.SEEK_SET:
            self.position = offset
        elif whence == io.SEEK_CUR:
            self.position += offset
        elif whence == io.SEEK_END:
            self.position = self.size + offset
        else:
            raise ValueError("invalid whence (%r, should be %d, %d, %d)" % (
                whence, io.SEEK_SET, io.SEEK_CUR, io.SEEK_END
            ))

        return self.position

    def seekable(self):
        return True

    def read(self, size=-1):
        if size == -1:
            # Read to the end of the file
            range_header = "bytes=%d-" % self.position
            self.seek(offset=0, whence=io.SEEK_END)
        else:
            new_position = self.position + size

            # If we're going to read beyond the end of the object, return
            # the entire object.
            if new_position >= self.size:
                return self.read()

            range_header = "bytes=%d-%d" % (self.position, new_position - 1)
            self.seek(offset=size, whence=io.SEEK_CUR)

        return self.s3_object.get(Range=range_header)["Body"].read()

    def readable(self):
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import zipfile

    import boto3

    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    s3_object = s3.Object(bucket_name="bukkit", key="bagit.zip")

    s3_file = S3File(s3_object)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(s3_file) as zf:
        print(zf.namelist())
```

Reference:

- https://alexwlchan.net/2019/02/working-with-large-s3-objects/

Comment: This is very clean, but it does not implement caching. Is that a problem in your experience?